# Protocol Not Supported (Android)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to develop application in phone gap.It monitors server jobs. Currently server is not available so I made my system as server. I put project files in the same directory where my server is installed. I am trying to access my files in main activity. But it is showing error on my emulator. Error heading is **Protocol not Supported**. I am sharing main activity file and html file below. Please look at these files.
Main Activity File:

```
package com.example.productionmonitor;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("Here");
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue",120000);
       super.loadUrl("file////C:/Program Files/Elixir Technologies/Tango/tomcat/webapps/productionmanagerserver/Monitor app/productionMonitor.htm");
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/productionMonitor.htm");
        //super.loadUrl("C:///|\Program Files\/Elixir Technologies\/Tango\tomcat\webapps\productionmanagerserver\Monitor app\productionMonitor.htm");
        //super.loadUrl("http:///localhost:8080/productionmanagerserver/productionMonitor.htm");

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is that **html file** which I saved in location(C:\Program Files\Elixir Technologies\Tango\tomcat\webapps\productionmanagerserver\Monitor app\login.html) and I want to access this file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/login.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
    var strFile ;
    function userLogin()
    {
        window.location.href = "productionMonitor.htm";
    }
    function init()
        {
            var xmlhttp = null ;
            try {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (trymicrosoft) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MsXML2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (othermicrosoft) {
                    try {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (failed) {
                            xmlhttp = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if (xmlhttp == null)
            alert("Error creating request object!");

            if ("withCredentials" in xmlhttp) {

                // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
                // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
                //xhr.open(method, url, true);

            } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

                // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
                // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
                xmlhttp = new XDomainRequest();

            }               

            return xmlhttp ;
        }

        function CallWebservice()
        {

            var req = init() ;

            var url ="http://localhost:8080/identityserver/domains/allData";
            req.open('GET',url,true);
            req.send(null);             
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState != 4) return; // Not there yet
                if (req.status != 200) {
                     // Handle request failure here...
                    alert("Call failed");
                    return;
                }
                // Request successful, read the response
                strFile = req.responseText ;
                parseDomainList(strFile);                       
            }
        }

        function parseDomainList(dlist)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strFile,'text/xml');
            var domain = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("domain");
            for (i=0;i<domain.length;i++)
            {
                var dname =domain[i].getElementsByTagName("domain_name");
                var domainid = document.getElementById("domain") ;
                var option=document.createElement("option");
                domainid.appendChild(option);               
            }
            alert(strFile) ;
            userLogin() ;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="login">

        <h2><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>Sign In</h2>

        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">

            <fieldset>

                <p><label for="email">User Name</label></p>
                <p><input type="email" id="email" value="admin" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='admin'" onFocus="if(admin')this.value=''"></p> 

                <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="password" value="admin" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='admin'" onFocus="if(this.value=='admin')this.value=''"></p>

                <p><label for="domain">Domain List</label></p>
                <p><select type="domain" id="domain"> </select> </p>                

                <p><input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="CallWebservice()"></p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div> <!-- end login -->

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter where you put the files on your windows machine. Neither your android device, nor the Emulator can never access them. That'd be scary, if you think about it.

You'll need to turn your development machine into a proper server and then access it with the special ip address 10.0.2.2 from the emulator, which is the development machine's loopback. If you're testing on a device, you'll need to access the development machine's local IP address, presuming you're on the same LAN.